# Can't import packages from user path

Tags: python, pip

I've installed some packages to user folder (*~/.local/python2.7/site-packages*), using pip. But Python can't find them.

I set the **PYTHONPATH** variable in **.bashrc** (and restarted terminal):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But it doesn't show up in site packages folders:

```
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/site-python', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/site-python']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` does not affects `site.getsitepackages()`. Check `sys.path`.

Comment: My mistake. It was an error related with virtualenvwrapper, not paths. Moderator may delete the question.